# Bootstrap v3 dropdown event handlers don't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please look at the jsfiddler here. It is the most basic example with no change in default settings:
http://jsfiddle.net/BsZ47/3/

```
<div class="dropdown">
       <button class="btn btn-default mybutton" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Days<div class="pull-right"><span class="caret"></span></div></button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <a>Hello</a>    
</div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>
    <div id="news"></div>
```

The event handlers that should change the text when the drop-down is shown/hidden, do nothing. Is it a problem on my side or did they totally forget to add the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the parent `.dropdown` element for the event.

```
$(".dropdown").on('shown.bs.dropdown', function(){
```

Side notes...

1. You should use a `<ul>` and `<li>` for the `.dropdown-menu` items.
2. You don't need to use a `pull-right` `div` to display the caret, it actually makes it look worse...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/Zf88s/)

Comment: Oh, great. Thanks. Actually in my real application, the button has a fixed width so I need the pull-right to show the caret on the right side.